# Index of object array refering to entire array when pointing to subobject

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm setting up a node-red system to compare GPS coordinates with coordinates measured by a triangulation algorithm. The msg.payload consist is an array of objects, with each object being a measurement.
Within each of these objects, there are two objects, one containing an array of GPS coordinates, one containing a list of triangulated coordinates.

When referencing the index of one of the objects in the msg.payload array, it changes the properties of all the objects.

The node-red application runs on IBM Cloud and is version 0.20.5.
A JSON-formatted object follows to present the data structure of the msg object.

```
"payload":[{"gps":{"coordinates":[0,0]},"tri":{"coordinates":[0,0]}},{"gps":{"coordinates":[0,0]},"tri":{"coordinates":[0,0]}}]
```

where the actual coordinates have been substituted with 0 for privacy reasons.

```
msg.payload[0].index = 0;

msg.payload[1].index = 1;
```

This results in the following changes:

```
msg.payload[0].index becomes 1.

msg.payload[1].index becomes 1.
```

msg.payload[n].index becomes 1, where n is a number between 0 and the array length -1.

How do I change the index field in just one of the objects in the array of msg.payload?

Comment: first of all it is not a valid `JSON` format, and on top of that none of the objects have the `index` property, please edit your question so we understand what is the problem

Comment: No, the index property does indeed not exist. The code adds the index property, which javascript is able to handle without issue. The problem is that setting msg.payload[0].index = 0 makes the index field 0 for all msg.payload objects. In addition, the JSON has been updated. I removed fields that were not relevant to the question, and forgot a few commas and missed a bracket, sorry about that.

This behaviour persists even if the field already exists.

Comment: Edit the question to show more of the code in the function node so we have more context about what you are trying to do